# Why does integer division return float?

Tags: python

From what I understand, the integer division `//` operator is guaranteed to return an integer. However, while `2 // 1 == 1`, I also get `2.0 // 1 == 2.0`. Why doesn't python produce an integer, and, is it always safe to cast the output to `int`?

Comment: `2.0 // 1` is not integer division, it's a float being divided by an integer (floored). Integer division would be `2 / 1` or `2 // 1`. Whether the result is or displays as integer or float, if I take the statement 'integer division' literally, to me that means "an integer divided by a number" or "an integer divided by an integer". I suppose you saw it as "a number divided by an integer", but when it comes to two different types in a statement, one needs to be coerced to work with the other. So in this case I would consider integer division to require both numbers to be integers to begin with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misunderstood the operator. It is a *floor division* operator, not an integer division operator.

For floating point inputs, it'll still return a floored float value.

From the [*Binary arithmetic operations* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> The `/` (division) and `//` (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. Division of integers yields a float, while floor division of integers results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

The result of flooring is safe to convert to an integer.

Note that Python applies these rules to almost all numeric types when used in binary arithmetic operations, division and floor division are not exceptional here, nor is this specific to integers and floats (try it with `import fractions` then `2 // fractions.Fraction(1, 1)` for example). The only exception here are complex numbers, for which floor division, modulo operator or `divmod()` are not defined.

Comment: I wonder what the use case of returning a floored float in this situation is. If I had to guess, it would be consistency with `1+1 == 2` and `1. + 1 == 2.`

Comment: @CharlieG: because it is consistent with other mathematical operations using different numeric types. This isn't limited to integers and floats either, it also applies to booleans, `decimal.Decimal()` and `fractions.Fraction()`. **All** binary arithmetic operations with two numbers convert those numbers to a common type (with a few exceptions for complex numbers where the mathematical operation doesn't make any sense).

Comment: I wonder how "stable" the result of floating-point floor division is. Should I open a new question about that? For instance, consider: `d = defaultdict(list); for x in [3.0, 7.1, 12.6, 15.4]: d[x // 10.0].append(x)`. Am I guaranteed that the numbers will be correctly grouped as `{0.0: [3.0, 7.1]; 10.0: [12.6, 15.4]}`? Or is there a risk that `12.6 // 10.0` and `15.4 // 10.0` won't be exactly equal?

Comment: @Stef: floating point division is entirely deterministic, not random nor dependent on any variable parameters, *and* you are using literal values for the floating point numbers. There won't be any variation in the outcomes.